# Using Facebook/ Instagram Graph API but Going Nowhere

Tags: facebook, instagram

I am building a web site for my sister which has thousands of images and followers on Instagram, I have been researching for the past 2 days of how I am able to get the Instagram JSON feed to my sisters site without millions lines of code and all the BS it entails to get simple data. All sources including Instagram and Facebook developer are outdated including hundreds of web sites with non-functional code.

I can program in PHP, jQuery, JS, Python etc... Asking for some help on this issue.

For example I can get the following working for a FaceBook call but not working for Instagram

[Facebook Graph working link](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cemail&access_token=EAAjuuCpWhX4BO1RgKuIFP76fMkpXZAki5yepR0xCEppL0srWK1bvyY0vEBpuWTl0QE1ZANV7M8DT7ZCMCgscRvpZCWktdkS0IqOm13Q5yAWOeEMKF9ObKpetJoZBavZBZBulucUZB1ZC9RWSx0EZCN0mypN5fZBXvWZBtrtsvYmpZCGzeOeZCjEfqvRZBW4OUnHg58gJYyI8oRmvO9JuzFhDFFvbAZDZD)

[Instagram Graph non-working Link](https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,media_type&access_token=EAAjuuCpWhX4BOwcCNdPZCKlXIkazFl8CQJB5RZCQ3S4AoFzNFh4dWD0qAr3OUyPM0wSAspxRdG6fUNXRkuNniUkgzcZADOlTibvw9hLWQrCBwM6K4CEb8ICZBMrZC8IwlxefQKLifonfhPKxZC25jiY019ykihIFrtbFnmn1PKZB0WgShWUPtvb9N9WZCQZDZD)

My App is registered with Facebook in development mode, I am honestly at a loss here.

Goal is to use my app to get my sisters Instagram token and embed it with code and have Instagram feeds on her site.

I am currently using my own tokens for my own FB and instagram

[My own instagram account](https://www.instagram.com/diegom_14/)

[My Sisters instagram account](https://www.instagram.com/hungrymonica/)

Probably missing something but in the 48hrs have read 100s of documents and still  nowhere. Please Advise

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/ - shows you what data you can get from instagram, and how to get it. Where _exactly_ are you stuck within that? It's unclear from that documentation where you got the idea that `https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,media_type` would be a valid URL. You appear to have munged two different endpoints together. Or maybe [something here](https://www.google.com/search?q=embed+instagram+feed+in+website) is what you need.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media#get-a-user-s-media: _"You will need the `instagram_graph_user_profile` and `instagram_graph_user_media` permissions, so request the `user_profile` and `user_media` scopes when you get authorization from the user."_ - Your token (which is still valid for about two month, and which you should rather _not_ have exposed here in the first place) put into the access token debugger, shows you only got `email`, `instagram_basic` and `public_profile`.

Comment: @ADyson there are two different APIs, the Instagram Graph API for business/creator accounts, and the Instagram Basic Display API for "normal" ones. So assuming the accounts in question are just normal ones, `graph.instagram.com` would be the correct API host name; the IG Graph API uses `graph.facebook.com` same as the rest of Facebook's Graph API.

Comment: @CBroe I know that. It was the `me/media` bit which didn't look right. The basic Display API reference lists  a /me endpoint and a /media endpoint. I didn't see anywhere that lets you put them together, but it looks like I missed it, it's effectively implied in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user/media#reading and shown in the guide you linked to, which I now see. Thanks.

Comment: for example I only want to use the basic display instagram account, but according to the documentation it is not possible with a business account...  What would the correct url look like for a basic display instgram account?

Comment: @Dango I think what CBroe's saying is your URL _is_ correct (it was my mistake to think it was wrong), but you're missing some permissions and/or scopes